# plugin:vite:react-babel Cannot redefine property: File

Tags: reactjs, node.js

can you help me how to fix this error

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaFcB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1QIB.png)

I type npm run dev and run the site but I get this error

[vite] Internal server error: Cannot redefine property: File
Plugin: vite:react-babel
File: D:/ertugrulv2/projeler/Full Stack E-Commerce Website Using React JS/admin/src/main.jsx

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.